# Getting gradle to generate different startup scripts based on distribution

Tags: templates, gradle, build-script

I'm using gradle 7.2 with the java, application, and distribution plugins.
In my gradle.build, is a section for statupScripts:

```
tasks.withType(CreateStartScripts) {
  def tplName = 'unixStartScriptTemplate.txt'
  assert project.file(tplName).exists()
  unixStartScriptGenerator.template = resources.text.fromFile(tplName)
}
```

The same template will be applied to all distributions.

```
distributions {
  distroA {
        ...
  }
  distroB {
        ...
  }
}
```

Can someone help with having gradle generate startup scripts based on the distributions.
I would like to have a template for distroA and a slightly different template for distroB

Thanks

The desired output would be a .tar and .zip generated for each distribution, where the startup scripts for each distribution could be tailored / different for that distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is only the `main` distribution and the `application` plugin is the one that creates one `CreateStartScripts` task and configures the `main` distribution to package it.

So if you have additional distributions that all are also getting the start scripts, you most probably configured that yourself. So just do not use the `CreateStartScripts` task that was created by the `application` plugin, but define own tasks of that type with the templates you want to have and package them into your distributions instead of the one added by the `application` plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the response/answer. Looking a bit deeper, seems like a cascade of several issues to get the different scripts into the proper distribution/build. I'm taking a simpler approach to just add a task to generate my alternate scripts and manually update the distribution files post build. Thank You.